# Can you have Hobby and Standard Dynos at the same time in Heroku?

Tags: heroku, dyno

Can you have Hobby and Standard Dynos at the same time in a particular Heroku APP?

I'm using Python, a django site with celery background workers. I'd like to use standard dyno's for the web but hobby dyno's for the celery workers.

Is it posible?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is NO.

You can only combine Standard and Professional dynos in the same app.

A workaround is to create another app with the same code (plus attach the same databases from CLI) but in the Process file start only celery worker, celery beat and celery cam.